# Избавиться от родительского тега SimpleXML

Tags: xml, php

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$track = $xml->addChild('root');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

Выводит

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><root></root></xml>
```

Надо избавится от родительского тега xml, и привести к виду

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root></root>
```

Comment: Невероятное рядом!

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');

Пустой тег сам закроется, что, впрочем, не несет в себе ничего страшного.

Comment: @Etki, благодарю, можно преобразовать в ответ наверное.